# PHP spl_autoload_register doesn't fire classes or unknown issue

Tags: php, html

I have running my php application in xampp 8.0.8 and I made a class folder with specific classes for my app and I used `spl_autoload_register()` to load them with namespaces but when I call class with an html renderer it doesn't render the tag and there is no error massage came out. But I have notice my html docs it doesn't load fully.

Network/Response the issue here is it was not continue rendering my html component from home

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>OMA</title>
</head>
<body>
//it cuts here...
```

App/autoload.php

```php
<?php

spl_autoload_register(function($className){
    $file = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $className . '.php';
    $file = str_replace('\\', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $file);
    
    if (file_exists($file)) {
        include_once $file;
    }
});
```

Here is my main method that has a static method to be called in the index.php

```php
<?php
namespace App;
use App\Web\Views\Home;

class Main {
    public static function run(){
        $home = new Home();
        echo $home->render();
    }
}
```

and my home component renderer
App/Web/Views/Home.php

```php
<?php

namespace App\Web\Views;

class Home {
    // display the home page
    public function render(){
        return <<<HTML
            <h1>Welcome to the Home Page</h1>\n
        HTML;
    }
}
```

and now calling the main static method from Main class to index.php

```php
<?php
    require_once 'App/autoload.php';
    use App\Main;
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>OMA</title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php 
        Main::run();
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

I don't know what is wrong with the spl_autoload_register because if I manually include the class file without the spl_autoload, it renders my home component.

Comment: did you check if you're not a `/` short in `$file = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $className . '.php';` - `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` has no trailing slash.

Comment: I removed the $SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] and it works, but when I will deploy this without $SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] does this still work?